# lowering MySQL load and memory usage

Tags: php, mysql, load

I'm working on new script. It's something similar to 9gag, there are posts and people like/dislike them and so on.

I have 3 tables for posts, users, like_status

for example:

posts table structure:

```
postid, postdata , userid, ...
```

users table stucture:

```
userid, username , ....
```

like_status

```
postid,userid,liked, disliked
```

I used to use MySQL query

```
SELECT A.*, B.username FROM posts A, users B WHERE A.userid=B.userid
```

then I get the like status by assigning the session userid to a variable `$SID` and use this MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM like_status WHERE userid=$SID
```

everything is working fine, but I'm a little concerned about the server load.

Which is better for server load and memory, to run joining query to be :

```
SELECT A.*, B.username, C.liked, C.disliked 
FROM posts A   
JOIN users B ON (A.userid = B.userid)   
JOIN like_status C ON (C.userid = $SID)
```

And what about if I'm using that query to fetch number of posts like 10 posts for example

```
SELECT A.*, B.username, C.liked, C.disliked 
FROM posts A   
JOIN users B ON (A.userid = B.userid)   
JOIN like_status C ON (C.userid = $SID)   
ORDER BY A.postid limit 10
```

.. Will it cause any performance issues?

That's it.
Best Regards

Comment: put code in `code` tags `

Comment: Post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` results for each table. There can't be proper query optimization without looking at the indexing for the table(s).